# Editing the content of a stringbuf in C++

Tags: c++, copy, ostream

How could I edit the content of a stringbuf without changing whats already there?.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main (void){
stringbuf str;
ostream output(&str);
output << "Hello";
cout << str.str();
cout << endl;

output << "Hello";
cout << str.str();
cout << endl;

stringbuf str2;
str2.str(str.str());
ostream output2(&str2);
output2 << "Bye";
cout << str2.str();
cout << endl;
}
```

The result I need is:

```
Hello
HelloHello
HelloHelloBye
```

But instead I got:

```
Hello
HelloHello
ByeoHello
```

Also, Is there anyway I can get this to work without creating new ostreams everytime I create a new stringbuf?

Comment: One question per question buddy

Comment: What makes you think you're not operating on a copy of the stringbuf? Looks like a cursor positioning problem to me.....

Comment: Oh sorry, yes it is. I need to edit this question.

Comment: While you're at it, add indentation, headers and namespaces.

Comment: _"edit the content of a stringbuf without changing whats already there?"_ Lol complete contradiction....... what do you think "edit" means -.-

Comment: _"Is there anyway I can get this to work"_ Get _what_ to work? What are you trying to do? What is your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to seek your new `ostream` to the end of its buffer:

```
output2.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
```

Otherwise new output will begin to overwrite the existing buffer.

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e4e0a676ebdba0f))